# WinForms tooltips not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, tooltip

I have a WinForms application. Each form and user control sets up its tooltips as follows:

```
// in the control constructor
var toolTip = new ToolTip();
this.Disposed += (o, e) => toolTip.Dispose();
toolTip.SetToolTip(this.someButton, "...");
toolTip.SetToolTip(this.someCheckBox, "...");
...
```

However, the tooltips don't appear when I hover over the controls. Is this an appropriate way to use tooltips? Is there something that could be happening in another part of the application (e. g. listening to some event) that would stop tooltips from working?

Note that tooltips on my outer form's toolstrip buttons (which are configured via the button's tooltip property) do work as expected.

EDIT:

I've observed this more and I've noticed that sometimes the tooltip does show up, it is just extremely "flaky". Basically, sometimes when I mouse over a control it will show up very briefly and then flicker away. I can get it to show manually with .Show() and a long AutoPopDelay, but then it never disappears!

Comment: not sure what you are doing elsewhere but your code does work for me, are you sure the usercontrol is enabled?

Comment: @MarkHall Do I have to explicitly set the enabled property to true? All of the buttons, textboxes, etc. on the control work fine.

Comment: No you don't. It will inherit the parents state. Something may be pulling focus away from the controls. Try attaching a handler to the ToolTip's Popup event and see if it is triggered.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion I have this sometimes as well and am here (again) seeking answers. In my case, the TT doesn't work until I unhide a tab page, tho the control with the TT is not even involved in the tab control. PS Hardly anyone tells you why they down-vote. It's very annoying. At least have the wherewithal to explain your displeasure, right?

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: in my recent case, a link label behind a tab control (brought to front of the TC) would not display the TT if I removed a tab page from the collection (the right-most in this case but I haven't tested others). If I didn't remove the tab page, or re-inserted it, it displayed fine. Bizarre.

Comment: I confirm this is an ugly Windows 10 bug. See answer from hypers for a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue when my tooltip was not showing up over the RichTextBox once in about 3-5 times it normally should. Even forcing it to show explicitly with *toolTip.Show* didn't help. Until I changed to the way mentioned by Shell - you have to tell **where** you want your tooltip to appear:

```
'Dim pnt As Point
pnt = control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
pnt.X += 10 ' Give a little offset
pnt.Y += 10 ' so tooltip will look neat
toolTip.Show(text, control, pnt)
```

This way my tooltip **always** appears **when** and **where** expected.
Good luck!

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround works. This problem is an ugly Windows 10 bug. It is difficult to reproduce. It happens in one Form and in another Form with identical code it does not happen. Mostly the tooltip shows up once and then disappears forever. A very ugly Windows bug!

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems ok to me. I couldnt find anything wrong in your code. But, it could be failed only when control is disabled. BTW, you can try another method like this. but, i would not like to suggest you to show the tooltip like this.

```
private void someButton_MouseEnter(...)
{
    toolTip.Show("Tooltip text goes here", (Button)sender);
}
```

You can also assign the location where tooltip should be displayed in `.Show()` method. there are some overloaded function that you can use. Read the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.Show(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about `ToolTip.Show()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following method to "propagate" ToolTips from parent controls (that have a tool tip set) to its child controls (unless they have their own overriding ToolTip).

It's designed to be dropped into the form or control you're starting with, but it could also just be turned into a static method where the "parent" argument is required.

```
/// <summary>Setting a toolTip on a custom control unfortunately doesn't set it on child
/// controls within its drawing area. This is a workaround for that.</summary>
private void PropagateToolTips(Control parent = null)
{
    parent = parent ?? this;
    string toolTip = toolTip1.GetToolTip(parent);
    if (toolTip == "")
        toolTip = null;
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        // If the parent has a toolTip, and the child control does not
        // have its own toolTip set - set it to match the parent toolTip.
        if (toolTip != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(toolTip1.GetToolTip(child)))
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(child, toolTip);
        // Recurse on the child control
        PropagateToolTips(child);
    }
}
```

Note that the behaviour is undefined if you're using more than one `ToolTip` instance to manage parent and child control toolTips.

Answer (score 0):

[see example on ToolTip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

I had also this issue and could solve it as follows:

// Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.

toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;