# User can't see toolTips on remote RDP server

Tags: vb.net, tooltip, vpn

I have made a VB.net program
When one of my users connects to a RDP server over VPN he doesn’t get ToolTips.
If he connects to a local RDP server over Lan - ToolTips works.

When I connect to both servers ToolTips works fine.

I have made at test program to try and figure it out. But same problem.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ToolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 20000
        ToolTip1.IsBalloon = True

        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Panel4, "Test4")

        Dim tt As String
        tt = "Test1 "
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Panel1, tt)
        tooltest1()

        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Panel5, "Test5")

    End Sub

    Private Sub tooltest1()
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Panel2, "Test2" & vbCrLf & "Test2")
        tooltest2()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tooltest2()
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Panel3, "Test3")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does the user get tooltips for other things, e.g. Explorer items? Is the RDP connection quality the same for you and the user?

Comment: The user does get tooltips in IE.
We are both connecting at the same quality. I tried turning mine down to 56k and I still got tooltips.

Comment: The answers to [WinForms tooltips not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192532/winforms-tooltips-not-showing-up) recommend explicitly setting a position for the tooltip - does that make any difference?

Comment: TX - That did the trick